# how do i get lower than native monitor resolutions to work properly?

Tags: nvidia, display, display-resolution

i recently installed ubuntu 22.04 in a dual boot configuration(i mainly use windows 10, complete linux newb here) to try gaming on linux.
im having some difficulty trying to use monitor resolutions lower than my native, for instance i have a native resolution of 1680x1050(16:10) but that's the only resolution of my aspect ratio which is available when i right click desktop and look under display, the rest are low 4:3 options.

also, im using an nvidia gpu with 510 proprietary drivers selected and when i go into the display options for the x server settings app, it does allow me to select other 16:10 resolutions eg. 1280x800, however those options are marked as 'scaled' and if i choose them the screen becomes very zoomed in for lack of a more apt term and if i move the pointer to the screen edges the desktop pans around with a lot of space off screen, kind of how it's like when you scroll the screen in an rts game :(

so could anyone help me figure out how to use a different resolution and have it look like it would under windows, please :) (if that's possible) Also as a note the reason i want to use lower resolutions is i don't have the most powerful pc and would like extra performance, it's how i usually game in windows.

Answer (score 0):

At first I was leaning towards getting xrandr to work with your setup but this seems to involved. It's still worth reading to get some ideas going.

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=212098

How are you connecting your monitor? I've had this problem when I've use a DVI to VGA adapter or similar setup. VGA is analog, all other connections are digital (DP, HDMI, DVI, Thunderbolt, Type C) so system might no be detecting your monitor correctly.

1. Read over that article and provide us with some more details.
2. Same problem when you boot from a live USB 'Ubuntu' drive?
3. Try downgrading Nvidia driver to an older version.
4. Switch to Nouveau Nvidia drivers and if that works to follow a guide to blacklist Nouveau and install Nvidia drivers.

I've spent many hours trying to fix broken Nvidia drivers and Ubuntu 22.04 is a lot easier to get things going.

If you're open to the idea Pop!_OS comes with Nvidia drivers already loaded to the OS installer. If you're looking for an easy to setup, gamer friendly, Ubuntu based operating system I'd recommend giving Pop!_OS (Nvidia version) a try.

Let us know what your figure out, or post more info about your configuration/system?